# how to fix the http header in the form of an array for the curl_setopt() function

Tags: php

I have made a program that requires a request header in the curl function, but when I run the program the following message appears:
You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument

please help to fix it

I use the function curl_setopt(........., $ headers) but the result is still

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Spotify-Lite/0.13.26.56 Android/25 (vivo 1719)';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result   = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument

Comment: Your PHP is vanilla? No oddball extensions? What version? Would like to see what you get with `var_dump($headers);`.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry - keep messing up votes on edit approves. Would undo if I could. Mea culpa. As for this question. Code works fine, something funky on OPs end or simply not actual code.

Comment: @ficuscr I use the termux (android) application to do code editing and run it, with the php package in the repository

Comment: Assuming you shared the exact code used to produce the issue then the problem is with your PHP environment. I can't reproduce the issue anywhere else. Again, PHP version and the var_dump would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround try this in place of the array approach when building out your `$headers`.

```
$headers = new stdClass;
$headers->header1 = 'User-Agent: Spotify-Lite/0.13.26.56 Android/25 (vivo 1719)';
$headers->header2 = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers->header3 = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
```

The only explanation I can come up with is your `array` somehow doesn't implement the [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class as it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array();
$headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//Then on curl
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution

Comment: the code is the solution.